# Wordpress deleted during basic customization

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, customization

I have a surprising problem with wordpress that happened 3 times. I create a wordpress trough  https://www.000webhost.com/ and after a few minutes of customizing a theme (shapely colorlib), i get a bug on any task i'm currently doing and get kick out the system.

If i try to come back, wordpress ask me to sign up such as i have no account yet. And when i do i get a long bug message.

I tried the whole process 3 times, deleting the 00webhost account and re-doing it. Twice with the same mail and once with another 'fresh' mail

The bug screen:

[image]

I put all the screenshots, steps and bug message here : https://docs.google.com/document/d/1IAPEF7Aq2UwBA9bHyqVVXrgWAG38pWPzLgSW4Llnurs/edit?usp=sharinghttps://docs.google.com/document/d/1IAPEF7Aq2UwBA9bHyqVVXrgWAG38pWPzLgSW4Llnurs/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks for your help, i'm not very experienced at all very wordpress but I don't see what i might be missing as i have done so few steps. Does this theme is stable ? Or any known problem with 00webhost and wordpress ? I don't know at all so thanks :)

Edit : This morning the site is live and working, i did not have to do anything, just wait for the quota to reset i think. Thanks for your helpful answers

Comment: Looks like wordpress generated a lot of database queries and your hosting probably has some hourly limit? Try talking to your hosting support.

Answer (score 0):

> That is happening cause [000webhost.com](http://000webhost.com) or the host account you
>   got have limitations. What i found from the screenshots you have
>   attached that you have exceeded max queries per hour.

**My advice is to change the theme as its exceeding your account limitations**

Comment: Thanks already for your answer :) You mean the theme i chose needs too many queries per hour in order to work correctly ? So i can't use it with this host whatever i do ? Or it's just that TODAY i have done too much 'action' ? 

Anyway i'll try another theme. But curious to know what is it exactly if it's possible to know

Comment: Yes, cause the current theme and  current plugins doing that